# Setting up the IMediaPlaybackService

Tags: android, service, playback, serviceconnection

I'm having trouble with the `IMediaPlaybackService` for Android. I'm told that all I need to do is place it into its package (in this case, `com.android.music`), however I can't get my project to build when I do this. The code for IMediaPlaybackService is as follows:

```
/* //device/samples/SampleCode/src/com/android/samples/app/RemoteServiceInterface.java
**
** Copyright 2007, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
** limitations under the License.
*/

package com.android.music;

interface IMediaPlaybackService
{
    void openFile(String path, boolean oneShot);
    void openFileAsync(String path);
    void open(in long [] list, int position);
    int getQueuePosition();
    boolean isPlaying();
    void stop();
    void pause();
    void play();
    void prev();
    void next();
    long duration();
    long position();
    long seek(long pos);
    String getTrackName();
    String getAlbumName();
    long getAlbumId();
    String getArtistName();
    long getArtistId();
    void enqueue(in long [] list, int action);
    long [] getQueue();
    void moveQueueItem(int from, int to);
    void setQueuePosition(int index);
    String getPath();
    long getAudioId();
    void setShuffleMode(int shufflemode);
    int getShuffleMode();
    int removeTracks(int first, int last);
    int removeTrack(long id);
    void setRepeatMode(int repeatmode);
    int getRepeatMode();
    int getMediaMountedCount();
}
```

However there appear to be several problems that prevent me from building my project with this file:

- The "in" keywords are causing Eclipse to give an error. The exact error is: `Syntax error on token "long", delete this token.` I'm not sure why there are "in" keywords there. They don't appear to be keywords in Java, what are they?
- Another error that occurs is `The type com.android.music.IMediaPlaybackService is not visible`, which is remedied by making the interface public.
- The final error is `Stub cannot be resolved or is not a field.` when I execute this line of code: `this.mService = IMediaPlaybackService.Stub.asInterface(service);` because there is not a Stub in IMediaPlaybackService.

Others seem to have been able to overcome these problems with ease, so what am I missing? It's probably something simple that I'm not seeing, but I've been wrestling with this for longer than I should have. Do I need to mess with my project setup?

So I've been able to build my project, but now I'm having issues with the service itself. Here is the code for my MediaPlayerServiceConnection class:

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.music.IMediaPlaybackService;

public class MediaPlayerServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {
    //  Tag for debugging.
    private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerServiceConnection";

    //  The service.
    private IMediaPlaybackService mService;

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlaybackService is connected!  Name: " + name.getClassName());

        //  This is the important line.
        this.mService = IMediaPlaybackService.Stub.asInterface(service);

        //  If all went well, then we can use the interface.
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Current track: " + this.mService.getTrackName());
            Log.i(TAG, "Artist: " + this.mService.getArtistName());
        } catch(RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        Log.i(TAG, "MediaPlaybackService disconnected!");
    }
}
```

...and here is the code in my activity that binds the service, but the onServiceConnected method is not being called, am I incorrectly trying to use the service?

```
//  TESTING MEDIAPLAYBACK SERVICE
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.music", "com.android.music.MediaPlaybackService");
MediaPlayerServiceConnection conn = new MediaPlayerServiceConnection();
this.bindService(intent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
//  END TEST
```

Comment: Similar code works for me. But, I can connect to service only if service is running.
You need to see errors to know why you are not able to reach till onServiceConnected.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310266/can-mediaplaybackservice-be-used-for-getting-information-of-currently-playing-au/10620084#10620084

Answer (score 0):

I tried binding to the media player service myself....never was able to. I simply implemented my own player service in less time than it took to try and use Androids...