# android -- is there any robust way to use the play/pause controls on lock screen?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

The default Android music player displays the current playing album, along with play/pause and next/previous track buttons on the lock screen. Is there any good way to use or replicate this functionality, without going through a lot of pain, or making the app slow or brittle (e.g. not working on all devices)?

Related (getting information from the built-in music player): [Can MediaPlaybackservice be used for getting information of currently playing audio file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310266/can-mediaplaybackservice-be-used-for-getting-information-of-currently-playing-au/10620084#10620084)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) documentation. I think think you can make use of the existing controls in the android os.

Comment: sweet, thank you so much! even though this question isn't so popular, I really appreciate it.